# How to properly export/require

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to export one function this way:

```
exports.query = function(request){
    conn.query(request, function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        return rows[0].id;
    });
}
```

and using it:

```
var mysql = require('./mysql');
console.log(mysql.query('SELECT * FROM tablename'));
```

Proceeding this way for getting a result involves `undefined` as output.
How do I to fix this, please?

Note that when I just type `console.log(rows[0].id)` instead of `return rows[0].id` it sends back `123`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide a callback.

Comment: @Scimonster, would you please more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the output is being returned to the anonymous function of the database query instead of the caller of the module. You can use a callback to return output to the caller of the module.

```
exports.query = function(request, callback){
    conn.query(request, function(err, rows, fields){
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback(null, rows[0].id);
        }
    });
}
```

Then call it like

```
var mysql = require('./mysql');
mysql.query('SELECT * FROM tablename', function(err, results){
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But why are you setting null into `callback(null, rows[0].id)`

Comment: It is a common convention that the first argument of a callback is reserved for an error, so since there is no error on the else, we return `null` in the error position. Alternatively, you can just do `callback(err, rows[0].id);` without the `err` check.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem of synchrony.

the `conn.query` function returns undefined because it finish its execution before the results are fetched (like almost any i/o related operation on js/node).

One possible solution to that, is to provide a callback to your `query` function.

```
exports.query = function(request, cb){
  conn.query(request, function(err, rows, fields){
    // some "special" processing
    cb(err, rows, fields);
  });
};
```

If you're not familiar with async functions, take a look on some articles about that:

http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/
 https://www.promisejs.org/